# BoxLayout and JTextField not working the way I need it to

Tags: java, jframe, jtextfield, boxlayout

I'm trying to create a basic login screen but when I run it, the text box is huge and increases when I maximize the window. How do I get it to stay with a fixed size?

```
public class LoginScreen {

    LoginScreen()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Box b = Box.createVerticalBox();
        JLabel title = new JLabel("Welcome to login screen");
        b.add(title);
        title.setAlignmentX(JFrame.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        title.setFont(title.getFont().deriveFont(20.0f));
        title.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20,10,20,10));
        Box c = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        JLabel login = new JLabel("Login Id");
        login.setAlignmentX(JFrame.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        JTextField loginf = new JTextField("");
        loginf.setAlignmentX(JFrame.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        c.add(login);
        c.add(loginf);
        b.add(c);
        frame.add(b);
        frame.setSize(450,350);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LoginScreen();
            }
        });
    }
```

}

Comment: If you don't use Box and for JTextField use setBounds(x,y,width,height)

Comment: I tried doing that for JTextField, but it doesn't work. Also, I need Box for the formatting, as the JLabel and JTextField have to be in a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

I realized it was as simple as using setMaximumSize().

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#size - got it from here.